# HTML5 with multiple off screen canvases affect performance?

Tags: html, canvas, prerender

I am using the following code to pre-render a series of images to use as an animation:

```
var renderToCanvas = function (width, height, renderFunction) {
var buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
buffer.width = width;
buffer.height = height;
renderFunction(buffer.getContext('2d'));
return buffer;
};  


function prerender(){

frames = [];        
for(i=0; i<20; i++)
{
frames[i] = renderToCanvas(200, 60, function (seq) {
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){
seq.drawImage(image,0, 0, 200,60);
};
    image.src = "animation/animation0" + i + ".png";
});
}
}
```

This makes 20 offstage canvases per sequence. Then:

```
context.drawImage(frames[count], 13, 80, 200, 60);
```

Does a pre-render improve performance in this case? I can also run the animation like this:

```
var disc= new Image();
disc.onload = function(){
context.clearRect ( 7, 235 , 200, 60 );
context.drawImage(disc, 7, 235, 200, 60); 
  };  
disc.src = "animation/animation00" + count + ".png";
```

Here is a link to the (unfinished) app:

http://tadjaland.com/spinningDisk/Yokogawa%20Spinning%20Disc-v0.html

(might require a refresh in Yahoo and IE to enable sliders, a problem I haven't figured out, yet)

Also, each time the specimen box is clicked, 20 more new off-stage canvases are created, This seems like it would cause problems.

My second question is: If a pre-render would improve performance, would it be better to pre-render all the images onto one off-screen canvas, like a sprite-sheet, or does the number of canvases matter?

Comment: I'd say it is much cheaper to create one <canvas> to hold your all backbuffer sprites, because the display driver needs allocate it only once. Then use x,y,width,height drawImage() magic to pick items from this backbuffer.

Comment: I'd recommend to create an benchmark at http://jsperf.com/ and share it :)

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?